# How to i add all the labels of my data to the x-axis of a matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i would like my graph to indicate all the data of my x axis and not remove some points automatically. My graph is supposed to indicate all the years from 2011 to 2020, except it skips every second year. Please help.

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = [2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020];
y = [139.1,128.6,115.1,109.4,104.1,111.1,119.4,128.3,137.9,147];

fig, (ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize = (8,4))


ax2.scatter(x=x, y=y, marker='o', c='grey', edgecolor= 'b')
ax2.set_title('Retail sales in South-Africa in billion US$') ##$$ makes text italic
ax2.set_xlabel('$Year$')
ax2.set_ylabel('Retail sales in billion US$')
ax2.grid(which = 'major', axis= 'y', linestyle = ':')
ax2.plot(x, y, c='b', )

for x,y in zip(x,y):

    label = y

    plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
                 (x,y), # this is the point to label
                 textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
                 xytext=(0,15), # distance from text to points (x,y)
                 ha='center')

plt.xticks()
plt.yticks()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're onto the right thing here: Take a look at [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-xticks-in-python/).

To get it to work the way you want it to, the only line of code I changed is `plt.xticks()` like so:

```
plt.xticks([2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020])
```